# Email attachment works fine in gmail but not on my mailserver

Tags: email-attachments

Using PHP i am sending email attachment on both my gmail and mailserver id(company email id). I am getting email in both of my email account but on my company email id my email attachment shows error(it doesn't open properly) whereas in gmail it is fine. 
Any ideas or suggestion?? 
I am pasting my php code here. any help would be highly appreciated.

HTML CODE:

```
  <form action="contact.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileAttach" id="file"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" align="right">
  </form>
```

contact.php:

```
                 <?php
               if($_POST['submit'])
              {

           $strTo = "mymail@company.com, mymail@gmail.com";
            $strSubject = "Attachment file";
            $strMessage = "Attachment";
                $txtFormEmail = "mymail@gmail.com";

           $strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: "."<".$txtFormEmail.">\nReply-To: ".$txtFormEmail."";

$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";

//*** Attachment ***//
  if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
    {
        $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
        $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
    $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
    $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
}


$flgSend = mail($strTo,$strSubject,$strMessage,$strHeader); 


  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP Mailer Class to send mails with attachments.